# Options sub-menu goes off-screen when enabling FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, android-window

I am setting `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag in order to have the status bar overlapped with the `ActionBar` and I have an options menu with a sub-menu.. the problem appears when I hit the sub-menu item, then it shows off the screen (its left edge can be barely seen).

When I remove the below flag, the sub-menu shows normally.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Here's the menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Items"
        app:showAsAction="never">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item2"
                android:title="item 2"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item3"
                android:title="item 3"
                app:showAsAction="never" />

        </menu>
    </item>
    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

And the activity if it helps

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue while keeping the status bar overlapped with the `ActionBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

set the second parameter of setFlags to:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
```

instead of

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
```

or simply replace your code with this:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
```